# How to add a firewall rule per country in google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to allow my trafic just from my country. How can I do it?
I know that I can create a rule specifying the IP range, but there are more than 1600 IP ranges to add. Is there any "easy" way?

Comment: This is rarely a good idea. You'll have lots of false positives and false negatives, and there'll be folks temporarily out of the country who may still need to access your site. Is it actually a *problem* if someone from another country loads the site?

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud VPC Firewall rules do not support geolocation.

To enable geolocation-based blocking you have several options:

- Implement a third-party software solution.
- Deploy a Google Cloud HTTP(S) Load Balancer and Cloud Armor.

Interesting article on third-party add-ons:

[How to Block IPs from Countries using Iptables Geoip Addons](https://linoxide.com/block-ips-countries-geoip-addons/)

Google Cloud Armor supports ISO 3166-1 country codes for geolocation-based rules (deny/allow).

[Cloud Armor: Allow or deny traffic from a specific region](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#allow_or_deny_traffic_from_a_specific_region)

Your question mentions `more than 1600 IP ranges`. Internet routing changes by the second and IP addresses can be remapped from one side of the world to another effortlessly today via BGP. As soon as you created a rule set, it would be incorrect quickly.

I do not recommended geolocation based blocking. VPNs hide the true source of traffic. During Internet outages, traffic can be rerouted. If your goal is to block traffic from bad actors, subscribe to an IP based rules list and block specific IP addresses for 24 hours and then refresh the rules list. If someone wants to access a geoblocked site, its takes about five minutes to georelocate traffic and defeat your blocking.

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud after 1 year dind't give any feedback on this, so moving to AWS that i see has this service.

I hate ineptitude, i've to work 24h giving everything and these huge companies just sit an laugh.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked. AWS does not support geolocation VPC firewall rules either.  You will find that you need a paid support plan with AWS as well if you require support.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/525919)

Comment: This information is relevant for those wanting this feature (that many open-source firewalls implement since years ago) and expecting a quick fix from Google, which obviously will not happen.